# Parse image size from identify command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, identify

with identify command I get some info about images and it looks like this

> my_image.png PNG 154x78 154x78+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 946B 0.000u
>   0:00.000

the image size it is 154x78

but I do not know how to put this values in variables

```
w=154 #But I want this 154 to be somehow parsed...
h=78
```

Note this script for parsing should work for all kind of images not just for the .png extension

also if possible I want to know what is the 0+0 in this line 154x78+0+0

Thanks

Comment: Please tell us __what you are trying to do__ - it seems that you have a _partial solution_ to a broader problem that you are having problems with. It is usually more help to ask about the original problem :)

Comment: this is the original problem I want to have the width and height of an image to a variable, the rest of the problem is easy to solve...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a difficult case to write a regex for, since we don't know if the file name will contain spaces or have an extension or not. Easier would be to use the `format` switch for `identify`:

```
identify -format '%w' filename.jpg
3360
identify -format '%h' filename.jpg
1080
```

In bash, you'd write:

```
W=`identify -format '%w' filename.jpg`
H=`identify -format '%h' filename.jpg`
```

The `+0+0` is the *offset* for the image, `+0+0` just means start at `0` on the `x` axis, and `0` on the `y` axis. You can read more [in the imagemagick manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry).

**Edited by Mark Setchell**

The foregoing answer is perfectly good, and I didn't want to add a competing answer, just a clarification, or minor improvement, that is too big for a comment...

As the OP is using `bash`, he can get both the width and height in one go, without opening the image multiple times, like this:

```
read w h < <(identify -format "%w %h" filename.jpg)
```

along with anything else, such as the colorspace and number of unique colours:

```
read w h c u < <(identify -format "%w %h %[colorspace] %k" filename.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk with multiple delimiters (space and x) should work

You could try with w = $(.....) if backticks don't work.

```
w = `awk -F" |x" '{print $3}'`
h = `awk -F" |x" '{print $4}'`
```

You need to fit in the identify command's output to the above, either by pre storing it in a file and passing that in, or including the call .

Comment: Spaces in the filename make this fail :(

Comment: Changing {print $3} and {print $4} to {print $(NF-8)} and {print $(NF-7)} fixes that :)